# Transfer size when serializable type with Durable functions

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I would like to check the size of data exchanged between orchestration and activity functions in Durable functions.

I would like to create code to convert a 5MB data frame into a dictionary type and check its size, as shown in the following code. However, when I actually run it, it returns a value of 216 and confirms that it is 216 bytes.
If I change the 1000*1000*5 part to other numbers, it still returns 216.

Why would it be 216?
Also, how do I modify it to check the size after converting it to a serializable type?

```
import azure.functions as func
import azure.durable_functions as df
import logging
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


# Client function is irrelevant
app = df.DFApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)
@app.route(route="orchestrators/client_function")
@app.durable_client_input(client_name="client")
async def client_function(req: func.HttpRequest, client: df.DurableOrchestrationClient) -> func.HttpResponse:

    instance_id = await client.start_new("orchestrator", None, {})
    logging.info(f"Started orchestration with ID = '{instance_id}'.")
    
    await client.wait_for_completion_or_create_check_status_response(req, instance_id)

    status = await client.get_status(instance_id)

    runtime = status.runtime_status
    output = status.output
    return f"runtime: {runtime}\n\noutput:{output}" 


@app.orchestration_trigger(context_name="context")
def  orchestrator(context: df.DurableOrchestrationContext):
    result  =  yield context.call_activity("activity1", "") # Receive size of dictionary type
    return  result

@app.activity_trigger(input_name="blank")
def  activity1(blank: str) -> str:
    data  =  np.random.rand(1024*1024*5) # Create random data
    df  =  pd.DataFrame(data) # Data frame creation
    df_  =  df.to_dict()
    return df_.__sizeof__()  # Check the size of dictionary types
```

Answer (score 0):

The size of the object in memory, rather than the size when serialized to bytes, is returned by the `sys.getsizeof() function`. This indicates that it calculates the size of the Python object, which includes the overhead of Python's internal data structures and references.

**You can make use of pickle module that is used to serialize the data produced by `np.random.rand(1024 * 1024 * 5)`. Next, calculate the data's size in bytes by measuring the length of the serialized data with `len` function**

My **function_app.py**:-

```py
import sys
import azure.functions as func
import azure.durable_functions as df
import logging
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pickle


# Client function is irrelevant
app = df.DFApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)
@app.route(route="orchestrators/client_function")
@app.durable_client_input(client_name="client")
async def client_function(req: func.HttpRequest, client: df.DurableOrchestrationClient) -> func.HttpResponse:

    instance_id = await client.start_new("orchestrator", None, {})
    logging.info(f"Started orchestration with ID = '{instance_id}'.")
    
    await client.wait_for_completion_or_create_check_status_response(req, instance_id)

    status = await client.get_status(instance_id)

    runtime = status.runtime_status
    output = status.output
    return f"runtime: {runtime}\n\noutput:{output}" 


@app.orchestration_trigger(context_name="context")
def  orchestrator(context: df.DurableOrchestrationContext):
    result  =  yield context.call_activity("activity1", "") # Receive size of dictionary type
    return  result

@app.activity_trigger(input_name="blank")
def activity1(blank: str) -> str:
    data = np.random.rand(1024 * 1024 * 5)  # Create random data
    serialized_data = pickle.dumps(data)  # Serialize the data
    serialized_size = len(serialized_data)  # Measure the size in bytes
    return str(serialized_size)
```

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]

```
runtime: OrchestrationRuntimeStatus.Completed

output:41943202
```

Comment: Are you saying that the 5 megabytes of data generated by np.random.rand(1024 * 1024 * 5) will be 40 bytes?

Comment: @TY00 Apologies for the confusion, Please check my updated Answer with pickle and len function